# Formatting a value to two decimal places, converting to string and then combining with a different column with like data

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I'm having issues with something like this...

```
Cast(cast(low_value as decimal(8,2)) as varchar) +' - '+ Cast(cast(high_value as decimal(8,2)) as varchar)
```

Where it seems to work at times but not at others.  I get a data type conversion is not possible.

Is there any other way to handle this type of formatting?  I tried using the convert function as well but that fails just the same.

Comment: I assume you are getting the error when low_value or high_value are null?  In those cases, what would you like displayed?

Comment: I thought that was the case but I then added a case statement where the when checks if low or high then null.  It works but there are some rows that prevent it to work fully and I can't figure out why.

Comment: what datatypes are low_value and high_value?  What actual error are you getting?

Comment: Figured it out.  Looks like there were bigger values than the 8 accommodates.  Wasn't expecting the rogue values so didn't think to check that

Answer (score 0):

Sry for posting it here and not in comments, but i dont have enough rep to comment. I think you need to use coalesce, that should solve your problem.

Example:

coalesce(low_value,0) now when you get a null value as a low_value, it will take the 0 and not null, so the conversion should not give an error out.